# Split td into three parts

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have use the following code snippet to create the Table. In this i want to separate the first column (`<td>`) to three different part

```
<body>
    <div class="minus">
        <table cellpadding="0.25px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <div  style='height:1px; float:left; width:24px'></div>
                        <div class='e-gridtreeexpand'></div>
                        <div style='float: left;width:10px;height:1px;'></div>
                        <div class='e-cell'> Row 1 Col 0 </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>Row 0 Col 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Row 1 Col 0</td><td>Row 1 Col 1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 2 Col 0</td><td>Row 2 Col 1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 3 Col 0</td><td>Row 3 Col 1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 4 Col 0</td><td>Row 4 Col 1</td></tr>

        </table>
    </div>

    <style type="text/css">
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .e-gridtreeexpand {
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-bottom: 10px solid black;
            border-left: 10px solid transparent;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```

In this above code working fine . In my working scenario I want to replace the `<div>` (`.e-cell`) for editing but it did not working properly. It will occupy the entire `<td>` instead of `.e-cell`. How to resolve this problem

Comment: _"i want to replace the div (e-cell) for editing"_ - Replace it with what? Are you saying you want to use JavaScript to modify the structure of the table? If so, what is the desired _output_ structure? (I'm assuming the above is the structure before modification?)

Comment: You could use three separate td cells in place of your 'row 0 col 0' td, and use `colspan=3` for the other rows. [*DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/T6JPY/2/)

Comment: If you wish to replace the `.e-cell` div with an input for editing then the best way AFAIK would be using `contenteditable=true` with `.cell`. [**Here's the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksRSB/)